# Enable EF Core Migration in Full .NET Project (*.csproj)

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a full .NET Framework project (*.csproj) with EF Core data access.

How can I have migrations enabled for EF Core in Non-.NET-Core projects (ASP.NET MVC5)?

I get the following error:

```
dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
```

Comment: You need to install the tools which contains the ef command: Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre

Comment: They are already installed

Comment: and you have also in your project.json "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
} ? if you have it also then it seem to be something wrong with your path or .net version nr.

Comment: @BassamAlugili, you didn't read the question carefully. There's no `project.json`, the project file is a *.csproj with packages in `packages.config`

Comment: ^^ sorry  I have forget that and the Tag .Net core confusing the reader.  In your case should be in your packages.config something like that :   <package id="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" version="1.0.0-preview2-final" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
This issue is closed on GitHub and one of the comments they have try it with 4.5 and they have the same problem :https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4797

Comment: I'm not sure this may help, because I didnt tried it... `dotnet ef` runs the command class inside the file `lib\netcoreapp1.0\dotnet-ef.dll` of that Nuget pkg. Try copying the dll into your current folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.0.0-preview2 and 1.0.0-preview1 releases of EF Core Tools don't work on csproj projects, only project.json. Use the Package Manager Console commands instead. See https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/powershell.html

Comment: Add-Migration then fails with "This command may fail unless both the targeted project and startup project are ASP.NET Core or .NET Core projects."